Do these sums always equal each other (in Gematria)? If so, why?
I am playing around with a Gematria tool, and notice that the reduced sum is equal across 3 different sums, not sure if this happens for every word, and not sure why it happens if it does. Hoping one might be able to explain. Probably something simple but I don't get it why it works out this way.
For example, we start by giving each Latin alphabet character a numerical value (specifically, we give it the ordinal value of its position):
a: 1,
b: 2,
c: 3,
d: 4,
e: 5,
f: 6,
g: 7,
h: 8,
i: 9,
j: 10,
k: 11,
l: 12,
m: 13,
n: 14,
o: 15,
p: 16,
q: 17,
r: 18,
s: 19,
t: 20,
u: 21,
v: 22,
w: 23,
x: 24,
y: 25,
z: 26,

We then generate 3 functions from this (don't mind the code, I will convert it as best I can into a math description):
export const listAlphabetSite = buildSiteLister(alphabet)
export const listAlphabetBase = buildFoldLister(listAlphabetSite)
export const listAlphabetSize = buildSizeLister(listAlphabetSite)


The first function creates a sequence of numbers based on the "site" (the ordinal position) of the letters. So for "dog" it would be [4, 15, 7].

The second function "reduces" each ordinal value to a single digit, by adding the single digits. So dog becomes [4, 6, 7].

The third function plugs the ordinal value as an index to a value array, which looks like this (I don't know how to represent this as a function/equation):
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000 ]

So "dog" becomes [4, 60, 7].


Well, here are the sums and reductions:

$4 + 15 + 7 = 26 = 8$
$4 + 6 + 7 = 17 = 8$
$4 + 60 + 7 = 71 = 8$

All 3 reduce to 8. Why does it seem to always work out that way? Will it break down ever?
A couple other examples where it also happens:
gold
  site: 38 = 2
  size: 101 = 2
  base: 20 = 2
sophistication
  site: 177 = 6
  size: 879 = 6
  base: 69 = 6

Can you explain the reasoning/math as to why the reduced sum is always the same for these 3 sums?

Short reason: This process of summing digits until you get to a single digit is called taking the digital root of a number. Any number and its digital root are equivalent modulo $9$; that is, they both have the same remainder when divided by $9$. This is not affected by multiplication by any power of $10$: $20, 200, 2000, \ldots$ all leave the remainder $2$ when divided by $9$.

More info at the Wikipedia plot summary for digital root here.
